# Differentiability of a piecewise complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider
$$f(z) :=\begin{cases}z^3/\overline{z}^2, &z\neq0\\0, &z=0\end{cases} $$
Must show it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z=0$. I can write it as $z^5/|z|^4$, but extracting $u,v$ from $(x+iy)^5/(x^2+y^2)^2$ seems too tedious. Alternatively I could write it as $r\cos 5\varphi + ir\sin 5\varphi$, which looks more appealing, But, does that mean $u = r\cos 5\varphi$? Do I proceed by implicitly differentiating $u$ w.r.t $x$? (analogously for $v$)

The second part of the problem tells us to show $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$ and whether this contradicts the theory. My conclusion is, if the equations are satisfied And both $u,v$ are differentiable at $(x,y)$ then $f$ is differentiable. Since contradiction of theory is not in question, we must show either of $u,v$ are not differentiable at $0$.

How does one do that, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the Cauchy-Riemann equations we only need to compute the partial derivatives. For the given function, the partial derivatives at $0$ are easily computed,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\cdot f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{x^3}{x^2} = 1,$$

and $f(iy)$ is for $y\in \mathbb{R}$ similarly nice, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0)$ is also easily computed. Splitting $f$ into its real and imaginary parts before computing the partial derivatives is more complicated.

Rather than looking at the real and imaginary parts in isolation, it is more convenient to show that $f$ is not real differentiable at $0$. From the above, we know that the only candidate for the real differential is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0) = 1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(0) = 0$, which then easily shows the non-differentiability.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last part. The partials w.r.t $z$ and its complement are so and so, why does that imply non-differentiability?

Comment: That alone doesn't imply non-differentiability. But a function $g$ is real-differentiable at $z_0$ if and only if there are complex numbers $a,b$ such that $$g(z) - g(z_0) - a\cdot (z-z_0) - b(\overline{z} - \overline{z}_0) \in o(\lvert z-z_0\rvert);$$ Then $a = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$ and $b = \frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}}$. In our situation, since we have only one candidate for the pair $(a,b)$, one needs to show that $f(z) - f(0) - 1\cdot z = f(z) - z \notin o(\lvert z\rvert)$, which is easily done.

Comment: By linearity of the partial derivatives, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (u+iv)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x},$$ and similarly for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. So computing the partial derivatives of $f$ gives you the corresponding partial derivatives of both, $u$ and $v$, at one stroke. Sometimes - like here - that is much simpler than first figuring out explicit formulae for $u$ and $v$, and computing their partial derivatives separately.

Comment: Is this always true that I can calculate the partials of $f$ w.r.t to the variables and then assess what the partials of $u,v$ are like?

Comment: No, it's a matter of experience to recognise when which approach is likely easier. Both approaches always work, but sometimes one is much more complicated than the other. A good principle is to look whether the other approach works well whenever the initial choice gets complicated.

Comment: Very well, thank you for the tips.

Comment: Yes, you can always calculate the partials of $f$, and get the partials of $u$ and $v$ from it, $\frac{\partial (\operatorname{Re} f)}{\partial x} = \operatorname{Re} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, and similarly for $\operatorname{Im}$ and for $y$. It's not always easier to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ than to compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ separately, but for functions of the given form - rational expressions in $z$ and $\overline{z}$ - it often is, and only rarely is significantly harder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36170/discussion-between-alvin-lepik-and-daniel-fischer).